# Xilinx XPS: use DIP Switch for select

Tags: xilinx, microblaze

I'm trying to use a DIP-switches as select-signal in another module.
So the DIP-switches are an external component.

I always get the following error:
    ERROR:NgdBuild:924 - bidirect pad net 'DIP_1_7<5>' is driving non-buffer primitives:
    ERROR:NgdBuild:924 - bidirect pad net 'DIP_1_7<6>' is driving non-buffer primitives:
    ERROR:Xflow - Program ngdbuild returned error code 2. Aborting flow execution...
    make: *** [__xps/system_routed] Error 1

How can I use the DIP-switches in my XPS project?
I don't want to use a Microblaze to read the values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved the Problem by using IBUF primitives on the module inputs, where the DIP switches are connected.